# Unabl to install PHP extension OpenSSL on OS X using phpize

Tags: php, macos, openssl, magento2, phpize

I have been trying to install PHP Version 5.5.34 extension OpenSSL for Magento2 because it won't pass the Magento process installation if I don't have OpenSSL extension. I don't seen to be able to install neither way with `phpize` or compiling PHP from source.

***phpize***

This is OK:

```
sudo phpize
```

This fails:

```
sudo ./configure` fail with error `configure: error: Cannot find < evp.h >
```

***Compiling from source***

This is OK:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/shar
e/info --sysconfdir=/private/etc --with-libdir=lib --enable-cli --with-config-fi
le-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php --with-l
ibxml-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-mssql --with-pdo-dblib --with-apxs2 --wi
th-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

This fails:

```
sudo make fail with error **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC", referenced from:
      _zif_openssl_pbkdf2 in openssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

Does anyone out there know what's going on and how to fix?